# Process dynamically created web form with JQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, webforms

I've been wrestling with a problem that I just cannot seem to solve. I've got a web form that is built from a MySQL query that's run from PHP and returned to JQuery that displays a gallery of movies that the user can give a numeric rating. I'm wanting to send the form back to PHP for processing and writing to the database.

```
function loadGallery()
{
    $('content').append('<form id="movieRatings" action="../php/saveRatings.php" method="post">).html();
    $.get('../php/getMovies.php')
        .done(function(data) {
             var query = $.parseJSON(data);
             for (var i = 0, len = query.length; i < len; i++) {
             var galleryMovies = '<div class="movContainer">' +    
                                '<div class="movie">' +
                                    '<a title="' + query[i].mov_title + '" href="../' + query[i].mov_title + '.html">' +
                                    '<h3>' + query[i].mov_title + '</h3>' +
                                    '<img src="../imgs/' + query[i].poster_path + '" /></a>' +
                                    '<input type="number" name="' + query[i].mov_title + '" >' +
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>'; 
             $('#content').append(galleryMovies).html(); 
                }
             $('#content').append('<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>');
    })            
    .fail(function() {
                $('#content').html("Epic Fail!") ;
            });
}
```

The form displays without any issues, but clicking the submit button doesn't even send the request for the "saveRatings" PHP file. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, I just can't seem to figure out what that is. My first thought was that it was because the gallery isn't part of the actual html, but from what I've read that shouldn't have anything to do with it.

And pointers/sugestions/insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't append `</form>` separately from `<form ...>` -- `.append` creates DOM elements, not tags, so the `<form ...>` is automatically closed. Check your browser's DOM viewer to see how the elements are actually being organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
$('#ID').click(function(){
    // do something here
});
```

switch to

```
$(document).on("click", "#ID", function(){
    // do smth here
});
```

Your first assumption was true, if the element is not part of the initial html, then any events bound to it won't work unless you go with my second approach. You can find more about this behavior in the jquery documentation.

L.E: same goes for the submit action, in case i was not clear with the click example:

```
$(document).on("submit", 'form#formID',function(){
   // do smth here...
});
```

Comment: So with the `$(document).on(...)` I'll need to put something in to process the name and quantity entered into each input box, right?